# Scala library for plotting interactive graphs

Tags: scala, plot, graph

I am looking for a scala library that I could use to plot some interactive graphs that would produce e.g. and HTML file. I am thinking about 2D line and bar charts. By interactive I mean some basics like zoom and unselecting lines I don't want to see.

I found [WISP](https://github.com/quantifind/wisp) which is very nice, but what I don't like is that I need a single output file with my graphs and don't want to start a server. (Basically, I could use WISP to get my graphs on a webpage, CURL it and save to disc and then stop my server, but this feels way too much)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of graphs? Graphs graphs or rather plots/charts? And what kind of interactivity?

Comment: Good points, I added more info to the question

Comment: How about my library: https://github.com/CheShengSu/scalaPlot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about http://lightning-viz.org/?

It supports Scala client. Sometimes, I use Jupyter notebook to talk to the lightning server to get interactive plotting. (or I can skip the notebook step, and get the interactive plots directly at the lightning server page)

http://lightning-viz.org/clients/#scala

It also supports a variety of interactive plots http://lightning-viz.org/visualizations/

Comment: It's actually quite cool, but I am looking for even simpler solution, sth along the lines: import this library, plot these graphs and get an html or similar file on my disc. That's it. No servers, no magic.

Comment: ic. That sounds like a ipython notebook workflow. A similar workflow is spark-notebook (an example: https://www.typesafe.com/blog/scala-and-spark-notebook-the-next-generation-data-science-toolkit)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using a data source (ie. sqlite if you don't want to run a service) with Tableau. Tableau is purely GUI based but it fits your use case. You can create dashboards and nothing beats Tableau for interactive data visualization.

They have a free version (with limitations) and free 1-year student licenses.